# Trying to start a new activity when the screen is touched

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, surfaceview, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to start a new activity when the screen is touched.The background is a resized bitmap. But the touch is not detected. Here's my code:

public class DispCover extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    bg = new DispCoverG(this);
    setContentView(bg);
   } 



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();


}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    bg.pause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    bg.resume();
}

float dtp(float dp,Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    return px;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    int action = e.getAction();
    int xd = (int) e.getX();
    int yd = (int) e.getY();

    int x = (int) dtp(xd,this);
    int y = (int) dtp(yd,this);

    switch(action){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    startActivity(new Intent(//));
    break;
    }
    return true;
}

public class DispCoverG extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{



    public DispCoverG(Context context) {
        //code
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth)
    {
        //code
    }

    public void pause(){
        //code
    }

    public void resume(){
        //code
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code

        }
    }
}
```

};

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write the below code under `setContentView(bg);`

```
bg.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

OR

```
bg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class));
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

implement `OnTouchListener` in Activity.

Comment: r u getting what you wanted??

Comment: right after posting the question, i figured that was missing. anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to catch the MotionEvents directly in your view:

```
public class DispCoverG extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
....
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
       // to dispatch click / long click event,
       // you must pass the event to it's default callback View.onTouchEvent
       boolean defaultResult = super.onTouchEvent(event);

       ...
       switch (event.getAction()){
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
               Intent intent = new Intent(DispCover.this, XActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               break;
             }
       return defaultResult;
       //return true; //this should work if you need just ACTION_DOWN
    }
}
```